# Docker-compose access LAN from containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

Suppose I have 2 services in my docker-compose:

```
version: "2.4"

services:
  postgres:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker_config/dockerfiles/postgres.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./docker_volumes/db/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql    

  initializer:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker_config/dockerfiles/initializer.Dockerfile
    depends_on: postgres
```

`initializer` accesses `postgres` using `"postgres"` hostname in the network created for this docker-compose file, but now I want `initializer` to also interact with some host in LAN, which `initializer` can't access now (all requests just time out).

I tried using `network-mode: bridge` on both containers and on `initializer` only, and LAN access worked, but `initializer` could not access `postgres` in these cases.

How to make both LAN and `postgres` container accessible from `initializer` container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to add another network to `initializer` service, not override the default. The code for clarity:

```
version: "2.4"

networks:
  lan_access:
    driver: bridge

services:
  postgres:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker_config/dockerfiles/postgres.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./docker_volumes/db/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql    

  initializer:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker_config/dockerfiles/initializer.Dockerfile
    depends_on: postgres
    networks:
      - lan_access
      - default
```

Comment: The "trick" is to add the default network as it grants access to the LAN.